# windows service won't execute

Tags: c#, .net, adobe

I have a simple service with .net using c#. When I deploy the serivce, I know that it's running because I can see files being deleted. However, the only task that doesn't run is the send the file to printer task. I'm using admin account on the service and it still not doing anything. If I run this same code in visual studio under debug mode, the service runs just fine. please advise on what I'm doing wrong. Thank you so much everyone.

```
const string flagNoSplashScreen = "/s";
            const string flagOpenMinimized = "/h";
            var flagPrintFileToPrinter = string.Format("/t \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", pdfFileName, printerName);
            var args = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", flagNoSplashScreen, flagOpenMinimized, flagPrintFileToPrinter);

            string processFilename = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine
                 .OpenSubKey("Software")
                 .OpenSubKey("Microsoft")
                 .OpenSubKey("Windows")
                 .OpenSubKey("CurrentVersion")
                 .OpenSubKey("App Paths")
                 .OpenSubKey("AcroRd32.exe")
                 .GetValue(String.Empty).ToString();

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = processFilename;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
            p.Start();
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            //if (!p.WaitForExit(10000))
            //{
            //    if (!p.HasExited)
            //    {
            //        p.Kill();
            //    }
            //}
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            p.CloseMainWindow();
            p.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately without you giving us an exception or stack trace we havent got much to go on here.

So, first of all, you need to find out which line of code fails when running as a "windows service" and not when you run the code "interactively".

One thing you could do is wrap your function with a try/catch clause and catch the exception and log it to a file.

In addition to that, another option would be for you to debug the code whilst it is running as a windows service and then put a breakpoint on the function in question and step through the code.

To do that, temporarily add the following code to the service:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (Debugger.IsAttached == false)
        Debugger.Launch();
    ...
```

Then, make sure you have visual studio open with your solution loaded.  Then, when you start your service, it will pop up a dialog and ask for you to either attach to an "existing instance" of visual studio or to "open a new instance".  Select the option to attach to an "existing instance" with your code open, and then you will be able to step through the code as normal, set breakpoints, etc, only this time the code is running under the credentials of the service.

From here, you should be able to track down the code that fails while running as a service.

Comment: the service runs fine if you run in with in visual studio. it just wouldn't run when you install the service on the machine.

Comment: Thats exactly what I mean. First add the debugger code I just mentioned.  Then Install it as a service on your machine.  Then start it from the windows services control panel.  When it starts, a dialog will pop up asking you to attach a debugger.  That will allow you to step through the code while its actually running as a service,